# Selecting a popup menu with javascript applescript

Tags: javascript, applescript, ui-automation, javascript-automation

I have a AXPopUpButton that brings up a contectual menu if you click it.
However, I can't seem to access the menu with javascript applescript UIAutomation.

```
pop = item.popUpButtons.byName("Select")
pop.click()
delay(0.5)
```

Then the menu shows up on the screen. However, "pop.menus()", "pop.menuItems()", "pop.menus.menuItems()" all returns length of 0. How can I access the popup menus using UIAutomation in javascript? Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever found an answer to this?

Comment: No! :( Dead end!

Answer (score 0):

After clicking you should call `entireContents()` for the whole window. And then, choose the necessary one pop up selection.